# Testing simple STI with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, sti

I have got a class, that is the base of some other classes that specializes the behavior:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :type, :name, :command
  validates_presence_of :type, :name, :command

  # some methods I would like to test

end
```

The class CounterTask inherits from Task

```
class CounterTask < Task 
end
```

This all works fine until I am trying to test the base class, since it must have a type.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "name_#{n}" }
    sequence(:command) { |n|  "command_#{n}" }
  end
end
```

How would you test the basic functionality of the superclass?

Comment: Shouldn't your test be written so that it tests the functionality, rather than the implementation? In this case that would mean you would test whether `CounterTask` has the attributes and other things it gets from `Task`. If you change your implementation, for example not using STI anymore. Your test could still succeed if your `CounterTask` keeps the same behaviour.

Comment: That is a good point. I just thought I will save some duplications in the test if I first test the base functionality and then the child classes... Perhaps this might be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can declare the definitions of factories as follow:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task, class: 'Task' do
    shop
    currency
    value 10
  end

  factory :counter_task, parent: :task, class: 'CounterTask' do
  end
end
```

And now you can test base class isolated from its own factory and the same for each inherited class.

Comment: I only needed to pass the `class` option to the child factory to make this work: `factory :counter_task, class: 'CounterTask' do` (no `class` option was necessary for the parent factory either).

Comment: @gabe Omitting the `class: 'Task'` also works for me, but, `parent: :task` does seem to be significant if you want the properties defined in the task block to be defined when using counter_task. So, with `parent: :task`, `build(:counter_task).value == 10`. If you don't set the parent, `build(:counter_task).value == nil`.